# How to execute system command in parallel in c++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, system, executable

Normally when I want to run a executable from a c++ code. I just use the code:

```
system("path\to\the\executable param");
```

Now, I want to run the executable file in parallel. I use 2 threads. The first thread will call:

```
system("path\to\the\executable param1");
```

The second thread will call:

```
system("path\to\the\executable param2");
```

However it doesn't run in parallel as I expect.

Is there in way to solve this?

Comment: what did u mean with 'parallel'? Do you men (brain example) `system("1.exe 2.exe 3.exe");`? or did you mean an asynchron call with own threads?

Comment: In Windows? Use `"start [options] program"`.

Comment: You are aware of how to use backslashes (\\) in string literals, don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run multiple commands as below:

```
system("path\\to\\the\\executable param1 &");
system("path\\to\\the\\executable param2");
```

This way both will run in parallel, and your program doesn't need to be multi-threaded for this.

Comment: Assuming the OP is asking about Linux/Unix style operating system.

Comment: But will it be possible to check the output of the separate executables? What would be wanted in my case is to have a way to read the output of the launched executables as well.

Answer (score 1):

- For windows: CreateProcess (see MSDN) function.
- For *NIX: first, spwan a child with [fork](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Process.html), then replace a child code with [execXX](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Executing-a-File.html) (execl, execle, execlp, execv, execvp).