# Using system() in parallel in C (Linux)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, system

My code has a large for loop that contains system().  I.e.

```
for(i=0;i<totalCycles;i++) {
    <some C code>

    //Bulk of the cpu time is taken up with the command below
    system(command_string);

    <some more C code>
}
```

This for loop can be easily parallelised insofar as an iteration does not depend on a previous iteration.  Normally I would use MPI or openMP to parallelise the loop.  However, I am not sure how to handle system().  There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595141/how-to-execute-system-command-in-parallel-in-c), but that was in the context of only parallelising system() only, as opposed to system() within a larger loop.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) man page, it mentions [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html), so read these man pages too.

You probably want to [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) all (or probably just many enough) your processes in parallel.

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It has several chapters on the subject (that I won't summarize here).

You'll need to define if you want to get the output of your parallel processes. I guess that you'll need to use [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and probably [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) handling the incoming (or outgoing) data.

BTW, unless your many processes are mostly idle, you probably don't want to fork a *lot* of processes. Having much more running processes than you have cores in your processors would probably make your system slow down or [thrash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).